# C poll() pipe() incompatibility on OpenVMS

Tags: c, sockets, pipe, openvms

I'm porting some code to OpenVMS and have stumbled upon a limitation.

There is a `poll()` function checking an array of sockets for events, but unfortunately, one of the file descriptors is created via `pipe()` function.
This is then causing a problem and `poll()` returns with `errno = ENOTSOCK`.

Reason for pipes file descriptor is to intentionally interrupt/cancel `poll()` by writing a single byte to its input side.

Is there a way how to create something similar to pipe but with sockets?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Are you sure it's `poll(2)` that is failing? There is nothing requiring `poll(2)` to return an error if the descriptor is not a socket, this is probably a bug with the rest of the code that deals with events.

Comment: I'm sure. Code that works flawlessly on linux is failing on OpenVMS.

Comment: @TomasSoltys Well, that doesn't mean it's poll failing. It could e.g. be recv() if you use that, as it doesn't support pipes on OpenVMS - while OpenVMS poll() is documented to support pipes. If you still need a workaround, use a socket instead of a pipe. A TCP connection is the one most similar to a pipe, but if all you need is interuptions, you could monitor a UDP socket in your poll() call , and send off a packet to yourself when you need to.

Comment: 1980 called and wants its operating system back.